# AWS Neptune Request Throttling - Using gremlin-go

Tags: go, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using golang for my new service, which uses [gremlin-go](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-go) library to query AWS Neptune.

But I am seeing a significant difference in query times using following methods :

1. Querying using Jupyter Notebook (Gremlin magic) - Around 4-5 ms (Using gremlin profile)
2. Querying using library in golang - Around 50 ms

The query is simple as such :

```
g.V("ID1").fold().coalesce(
                        __.unfold(),
                        __.addV("LABEL_1").property(id, "ID1").property("prop1", "val1").property("prop2", "val2")
                ).as("NODE1").V("ID2").addE("LABEL_2").to("NODE2").property("prop1", "val1").property("prop2", "val2").property("prop3", null)
```

Client Side Configurations :

```
// Creating this driver once globally in service and reusing this for service lifetime
drc, err := gremlingo.NewDriverRemoteConnection(config.NEPTUNE_DB_WS_URI,
        func(settings *gremlingo.DriverRemoteConnectionSettings) {
            settings.TraversalSource = "g"
            settings.Logger = logger
        })

// Creating Traversal_() for every query - Is this fine?
g := gremlingo.Traversal_().WithRemote(&dr.dbClient)

resp, err := g.Query().Goes().Here().Iterate()
```

Additional FollowUps :
Is anyone else using `gremlin-go` in production at scale? Would I benefit on using http gremlin request instead of using this library?

My service requires me to handle over 10-50k write/requests per second (Sudden bursts of requests at times). My current setup is facing RequestThrottling on AWS Neptune. Suggest any better setup which I could use for graph db

Comment: Can you describe what you are seeing in terms of throttling?  Also, can you please describe your client configuration in Go and how connections are being reused (if at all)?  If you're creating a new connection upon each requests, there will be a significant penalty to query time upon each requests. It is best to reuse connections and measure your query latency based on long-lived connections.

Comment: Hey @TaylorRiggan! Have updated the question. Receiving `ThrottlingException` and also at time `TimeLimitExceeded`.

Comment: That typically means you're throwing too many requests at a very small instance and you're exceeding the query queue (which can hold around 8,000 requests). You should review: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/instance-types.html  For this type of use case, you may want to investigate using Neptune Serverless.  You also may want to look into batching your writes, when possible.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-multithreaded-writes.html